# How to get all value after where contain in sql

Tags: mysql

I get stuck in query of sql for this task

If i get all field after contain value 2 and ignore before value 2

For example like this

```
id profile_id status
1  1          3
2  1          3
3  1          2
4  1          1
5  1          1
```

and the result when i try like this,  show all values where not contain 2

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `status` <> 2 

id profile_id status
1  1          3
2  1          3
4  1          1
5  1          1
```

i try code subquery like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM   `users` 
WHERE  `users`.status != (
SELECT us.status 
              FROM   `users` us
              WHERE  us.status = 2 LIMIT 1)
```

and the result show like this

```
id profile_id status
1  1          3
2  1          3
4  1          1
5  1          1
```

The result should i expected be like this, just show all field after the status = 2

```
id profile_id status
4  1          1
5  1          1
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please include your data and expected results as part of your question, not links to pictures, and please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We would really like to help you, but you need to provide more details, especially what you've tried. And please do not provide links to some images, add your code here. Also get familiar with [How to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section, otherwise your  question can be flagged as off-topic.

Comment: @john thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @Dragonthoughts thanks for your suggestion

Comment: anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   `users` 
WHERE   id > (
                SELECT id 
                FROM   `users`
                WHERE  status = 2
              )
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it just show all value > 2, i want result get all field after status = 2

Comment: updated subquery to get the id of record with status = 2 and the main query will fetch other records greater than subquery return id value. it will return next 2 records with id - 4 & 5

Comment: @BonnyAUlia   happy to help you... you can also one upvote :)

Comment: i promise if i got 15 reputation, i will give you one upvote